# Java - Iterate an increasing number of elements

Tags: java

I want iterate in Java trough an increasing number of elements, this the code i was thinking about but I'm not sure about it:

```
for (int i = 0; i<=maxSomething; i++) {  
    action(i);

    for(String a : ArrayOfString)
       otherActions();
}
```

What i want to do is that:

- i = 0: perform action(0)
- i = 1: perform action(0) and action(1)
- i = 2: perform action(0), action(1) and action(2)
- i<=maxSomething: perform all actions

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need nested loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= maxSomething; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
        action(j);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Axel: This was not fast. He took 90 seconds to write this?

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux I saw the popup "load new answers" when I was still typing, thought it was rather something like 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Have a nested for loop, iterating a new variable, j, from 0 to i, containing action(j). This will get called from 0 to i.

Answer (score -1):

#### Update

I saw the below recursive function only gives result for one sequence of actions.

```
public static void recursive (int i) {
    action(i);
    if (i > 0) 
        recursive(--i);
}
```

So instead use an nested loop,it's preferred.

*Recursion bloats the stack.*

Comment: Nah... Java isn't Lisp. I think this is less readable for the standard Java developper (and bloats the stack).

Comment: ...and when you call this with `i` in the thousands, you'll get a `StackOverflowError`. Tail recursion is a poor solution here.

Comment: @SeanOwen Ok,thanks for the explanation, I think there was no point of posting a similar answer as Jespers. Either way it's not the preferable answer but still it's not a wrong one. Or is it?

Comment: Tail optimization by compiler can covert recursion to iteration, but this might be problematic to ensure in Java, so @Axel is right. Still +1 for recursive.

Comment: As of today, AFAIK Java doesn't have tail recursion, and what's more, the code above cannot be optimized by tail recursion (because the recursive call isn't a tail call).

Comment: -1 for bad use of recursion. It cannot even be optimized if java had tail recursion. Because there's a statement after the recursive call. Hint: recursion works when the call depth is shallow, like in a quadtree.

Comment: @Johan before I delete my answer as not constructive could please tell me if the second one makes any difference?

Comment: The problem with Java is that it does not optimize tail recursion. This will cause several things: Modern CPU's have a stack cache (8 or 16 calls deep). If the call depth exceeds that depth calls will be mispredicted, causing a call that would take 1 cycle to now take 16 to 100 cycles. This makes deep recursion quite slow. The other problem is the possibility of stack overflow. Further note that the 2 code samples are not equivalent. You need an extra `if` in the second one.

Answer (score -2):

Does the action change after each iteration, action(0) once done- can this be reused when called in the next loop run ? If yes, you should use recursion here.